# Sip over voip based calling on Asterik Server using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, sip, webrtc

I am looking for voip based sip calling tutorial on any PSTN, Mobile or Telephone number etc using Asterik server and also help how to allow websocket or websocket secure. The goal is i want to build an javascript sip calling app in phoneGap. Please help me, how can i implement sip calling in javascript.

Comment: I am guessing you already looked into [SIPML5](http://sipml5.org/) as it does exactly this.

Comment: Yes, I had survey simpl5.org but i think they couldn't guide their followers as like JSSIP.net

Comment: while, either way, you will need a breaker between the webrtc connection and the sip client. You can try the [Janus Gateway](https://github.com/meetecho/janus-gateway) to decrypt and get rtp streams to send to the server but you will still have to handle media going the other way and the initial negotiation during connection setup.